# Admob status is inactive but test ads work correctly

Tags: android, admob

My admob status is inactive - however, people have downloaded my app and I have done the test ad on my mobile phone and it work.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: did you set test mode to false?

Comment: thanks for the help, It just took like 24 hours for the Admob website to update my status.

Comment: @vnshetty - Where I can set it ? Actually in `admob` my app is inactive and this is message - `inactive: AdMob has never received an ad request for your site` How to active it ?

Comment: @Vakul Saini got to Admob developer console and select your app -> app settings -> test mode (Disable test mode for all requests)

Comment: Thanks ! But still it is showing me same :( And my one app which has test mode for client mode is active .... I'm confused :(

Answer (score 0):

Please check you have set correct **publisher ID** and also **remember** that AdMob take up to a 48 hour delay in reporting. That could be an issue if you just setup your account.

For further information please visit

http://support.andromo.com/kb/common-questions/how-to-get-an-admob-publisher-id